# how to fix NullPointerException in java gui?

Tags: java, sql, swing, plsql

I designed the login interface, and it compares the information that you entered with the information that is in the database. When I step on the login, this problem appears. I read about this problem and understood that it occurs when I call the value in the variable, but there is no value in the variable to call it.

But the variables that I want to compare with have values that I entered

```
 private void admin_loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        

//These are the variables in which the username and password that you entered are stored and compared to them
        
        String namee=name_admin.getText();
        int pass=Integer.parseInt(pass_admin.getText());   
        


        try {




    line 128     pre=con.prepareStatement("Select * from adminn where adm_name='"+namee+"' and adm_password='"+pass+"'");

            ru=pre.executeQuery();

            if (ru.next()) {

                System.out.println("login done");
            } else {
                System.out.println("login faild");
            }

        } catch (Exception er) {

            er.printStackTrace();

            System.out.println(er);
        }


    }                                           

    private void back_libActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        library ii = new library();

        dispose();

        ii.setVisible(true);


    }
```

This is the code where the problem occurred

`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ad_login.admin_loginActionPerformed(ad_login.java:128)
```

Here is a screenshot of the database that I want to compare against
[screen shot of database](https://a.top4top.io/p_2522jbl7e1.png)

And this is a picture of my entries in the login interface

`[screen shot of my input in login form](https://b.top4top.io/p_2522iirw02.png)

I checked the variables and it turned out that they are correct and there is nothing wrong with them

Comment: An NPE in marked line 128 can only occur if `con` is null.

Comment: looks unrelated to swing (or any ui code): solve the connection problem separately, only after that's working move on to add ui.

Answer (score 0):

On line 128,

```
 pre=con.prepareStatement("Select * from adminn where adm_name='"+namee+"' and adm_password='"+pass+"'");
```

Check the connection object, con, is the only object, on that line that can raise that exception.

Comment: [link https://l.top4top.io/p_2522drbji1.png ] I checked it and I think there is no error in it, and here is a screenshot of the code 

@mzm